# MVC View Showing Field Title Not The Field Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Details View that I want to show only what I retrieve from the DB. I don't want to see titles(labels) of the fields in my view. 
Here is my code of the view:

```
@model SozlukRG.Models.KelimeTuru

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>


<fieldset>

    <legend>KelimeTuru</legend>
    <div class="div1" style="display: table; background-color: #b0c4de;">
        <div class="div1" style="display: table-row;">
            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                <div class="display-field">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Kelime.Kelime1)
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                <a href="/Audio/@Model.Ses.Adi"> <img src=" http://www.seslisozluk.net/img/pronunciation.png" /></a>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="div1" style="display: table-row;">
            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                <div class="display-field">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Anlam)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="div1" style="display: table-row;">

            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                <img src='/Resim/Show/@Model.Id'>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="div1" style="display: table-row;">
            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                    <source src="/Videos/@Model.Video.Adi" type="video/mp4">

                </video>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Kelime.Kelime1)
    </div>


</fieldset>
<p>

    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")

</p>
```

**model.Kelime.Kelime1 and model.Anlam** are retrieving labels of the fields.
However,they are supposed to retrieve field contents.
Could you please help me correct my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
<div>@Model.Anlam</div>
```

or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Anlam)
```

Comment: The first code that you wrote gives an error saying "model" statemant is not allowed in a file..@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Anlam) this retrieves fine buy it became an editable textbox, could we disable editing ?